# Nested keys in redis using Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, caching, java-8, redis

I want to run a job in spring boot using quartz where multiple threads will execute the method.
What i want is to save the result in redis for every processing, so i can get idea how good job is working.

I want to save data in redis in this form.

```
{
  "2020-04-20": [
    {
      "item_1": {
        "success": "true",
        "message": ""
      }
    },
    {
      "item_2": {
        "success": "true",
        "message": ""
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to insert all the items in key date.
Since multiple threads are working , every thread is working on some item. So all item should be inserted into only key (date).

Is it possible?

one solution is to over-write the data of (date) key again and again , first getting data from redis, appending item on it and again saving the key in redis.

Is there another way , or using some annotation like @cacheable, @cacheput etc. so that i can create nested key. automatically item is appended in the (date) key.

Comment: Did you check the Redis Module https://redisjson.io?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it using redis set functionality.
I am using jedis client in my project.

```
It has very useful funtions like:-
 1) sadd => insertion of element.O(1)
 2) srem => deletion of element in set.O(1)
 3) smembers => getting all results.O(N)
```

This is what i needed.
In my case date is the key, and other details (one object of json) is the member of the set. So, i convert my json to data to string when adding memeber in set, and when getting data i convert it back from string to json.
This solved my problem.

Note:- There is also list functionality that can be used. But time complexities for list are not O(1). In my case i am sure i will not have duplicates so set works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered RedisJSON?
Soemthing like this (I haven't tested it, I don't have RedisJSON handy)

```
JSON.SET "2020-04-20" . []       // create the object once

JSON.ARRAPPEND "2020-04-20". '{  // every thread issues a command like this.
      "item": {
        "success": "true",
        "message": "thread 123"
      } }'

JSON.ARRAPPEND "2020-04-20". '{  // every thread issues a command like this.
      "item": {
        "success": "true",
        "message": "thread 456"
      } }'
```

`JSON.ARRAPPEND` are supposed to be atomic.

Comment: Yeah , redisjson gave this functionality which i want to acheive.
But i don't know earlier about the set functionality redis gave.
I am using jedis client where i find srem, smembers,sadd. All functions have O(1) time complexity. That is what i need.